# How to put a horizontal scroll in wordpress menu item

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I got a problem with menu and adding scroll to it.

I dont want horizontal scroll, I want vertical scroll and then when I hover over lets say "GELOVI" in shop I want that sub menu to pop out like it does without a scroll.

If you didn't understand me clearly please ask I will do my best to explain a bit more.

This is the website:
[Rich Nails](https://www.rich-nails.com)

Item in menu for scroll to be added to is called shop.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: your website cant open , if this problem in CSS maybe you need overflow-y: scroll;

Comment: It opens for me normaly. I tryed that and this second sub menu doesent open then, it is like hidden behind  the screen, its really weird.

Comment: maybe your site blocked in my country , okay lets try VPN haha ,  your problem at menu navigation > Shop ?

Comment: Yes, thats it, I just cant find a solution.

Comment: Your menu works well, but it is not clear how you want to modify it. Perhaps you are looking for a Mega Menu, try using a WordPress plugin for Mega Menu.

Comment: I am trying to implement scroll to it becouse it is too big.
But when I add scroll using CSS i get the horizontal one also -> which I do not want.
Tehn I remove horizontal one and then I dont see other sub menus.

I hope i explained this well :)

If I did not please tell me I will put more effort to it :)